# (Xcode) Parse. How can I delete a row in the table WITHOUT using PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm working in Xcode, and since I'm using Parse, I want to delete a row in the table without using `PFQueryTableViewController` because when I change `UIViewController` to `PFQueryTableViewController`, my app crashes.

Here is my code:

```
PFObject *object = [self.datasource objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row];
// Remove the row from data model
[object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
     if (succeeded){
        [self refresh]; // this is my function to refresh the data
     } else {
        NSLog(@"DELETE ERROR");
     }
}];
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're solving the wrong problem. You should instead work towards solving your app's crash. Don't bypass `PFQueryTableViewController`.

Comment: Yeah, you should resolve the crash. What's the error? How are you going about deleting the row?

Comment: which part of your current implementation is not behaving as expected when using `UIViewController`?

Comment: Did you drag a UIViewController onto the storyboard instead of a UITableViewController? A PFQueryTableViewController cannot be a UIViewController.

Comment: Oh! i see. Easy to miss. Thanks to you, Jacob and others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you drag a UIViewController onto the storyboard instead of a UITableViewController? A PFQueryTableViewController cannot be a UIViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest u use: PFQueryTableViewController and figure out why your app is crashing. Also, ur code looks good to delete a row.